# Помогите telegram bot pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, download

Как сделать так что бы когда боту в телеграмме кидали видео, он его скачивал куда то по указанному пути? может есть какое то апи или в самом pytelegrambotapi, не могу найти помогите.

Comment: [тут навернякая найдутся дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btelegram-bot%5D+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE)

Comment: Да но там везде как отловить айди этого видео но как установить по этому айди, может есть какая то функция download в python что бы скачать файл, может вы знаете?

Comment: [python скачать файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/download_file_example.py